# Converting app from Asp classic to python http error 502.2

Tags: python, iis

I have an old legacy application built entirely in asp classic, this is still used on a daily basis so am i looking at converting to python page by page. At the moment i dont know python but i am just trying to test the principle but when i run my python page below i get the http error 502.2 bad gateway. I have setup my handler mappings for python and everything is installed in the same directory as my original application with the same permissions. Any ideas please?

```
print
print ('Status: 200 OK')
print ('Content-type: text/html')
print

print ('<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Python Sample CGI</TITLE></HEAD>')
print ('<BODY>')
print ('<H1>This is a header</H1>')

print ('<p>') #this is a comment
print ('See this is just like most other HTML')
print ('<br>')
print ('</BODY>')
```

Comment: 1) Learn a framework like Django so you won't have to generate raw HTML like that, https://www.djangoproject.com/. 2) Switch to Linux, as running Python web apps on Windows is tougher than ever after the components are deprecated, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019

Comment: thanks if i go look at django is there a way to get that to work around my existing asp application where i am only changing pages in turn to python?

Comment: try to use the below code to just print the data in python:

    `print('Content-Type: text/plain')
    print('')
    print('Hello, world!')
    
    number1 = int(5)
    number2 = int(3)
    mul = number1*number2
    print(mul)`